# Force entry url

Tags: apache, url, seo, redirect

For SEO purposes. How do I force user gets redirected to mysite.com/index when types mysite.com on browser ?

I've tried Redirect / en/index
But I'm getting "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request to this address in a way that will never end."

Also, can this redirection consired set language (php psession, cookies?)

p.s. xampp/windows

Answer (score 1):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) works on path prefixes. `Redirect / …` matches any path its prefix is `/` (so virtually any path). Use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /en/index
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you're getting from Firefox is because you're entering an infinite loop with this redirection. If you try to redirect to a page that doesn't exist, and your server is set up to redirect to a page that doesn't exist on 404, you'll enter a loop. So, ensure that your redirect is going somewhere significant. Does /index exist? Try redirecting to Google instead and see if you get the same error.

(My server knowledge is limited to goofing around while working on school projects, so take anything I say with a grain of salt)

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you have an error in your redirect code. What Firefox is detecting is that the page are trying to view is redirecting you to itself. Without this protection it would just seem like the page wasn't loading.

If you are running windows on your workstation, I would recommend downloading [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It will let you see the series of redirects that your server is sending.